# There are less distraction vs. there is less distraction

Tags: grammaticality, subject-verb-agreement

I have trouble distinguishing if a noun like distraction or chance is plural or singular.

Is it grammatically correct to say

"It's more beneficial to drive alone because it's more relaxing and there **is** less chance of getting in an accident because there **is** less distraction in the car."

Or should it be "there are less chance of..." "there are less distraction..."

Or should it be "there is a less chance of..." "there is a less distraction"

And are there any awkward or non native wordings in this sentence?

Comment: Nouns chance and distraction can be used as countable and uncountable nouns. When used as an uncountable noun,  you say there is less chance/distraction. When used as a countable plural noun, you usually say  there are fewer chances/distractions. Somc people use less for countable plural nouns, but mostly people use fewer. So we shouldn't use less instead of fewer.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing awkward about your sentence, just keep the same pluralisations

> is -> chance, distraction
>   are -> chances, distractions
>
> "there **is** less chance of..." "there **is** less distraction..."
>   "there **is** less chance of..." "there **are fewer** distraction**s**..."
>   "there **is** less **of a** chance of..." "there **are fewer** distraction**s**..."
>
> "there **are** less chance**s** of..." "there **are fewer** distraction**s**..."

You can use it to ask the question *(singular)*

> Are there less chances of an accident if I use the highway? (*plural)*

or you can ask the question**s** *(plural)*

> Is there less chance of an accident if I use the highway? *(singular)*
>   Will there be less distraction?  *(singular)*

Comment: Does it matter if I use either plural or singular when I'm asking a question? Like should I've said "...when I'm asking questions?" Instead of "...when I'm asking a question?" In the sentence before? @Peter

Comment: @Maimai No, using single **question** or plural **questions** only matters if you are asking **one** or **more than one** question, it does not effect pluralisation of chance or distraction. Have updated my answer.